# Can Eloquent generate a WHERE clause like "WHERE (column_1 OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)"?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to make eloquent generate a query with a WHERE clause precisely like the example in the title?

The closest I got was with Where() and orWhere(), but that outputs

`(column_1 IS NOT NULL OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)`,

which gives different results than the query in the title!

Can someone also explain why these two WHERE clauses give different results?

Comment: The where clause in your title is checking for is column_1 true (a boolean), and column_2 not null.

Comment: You can do anything with `->whereRaw()`, like `->whereRaw('column_1 OR column_2 IS NOT NULL')`, but is that even valid SQL? The `(column_1 IS NOT NULL OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)` seems like the valid one to me...

Comment: I cannot find a good duplicate target about how OR works in SQL without knowing which flavor of SQL you are using, since Laravel supports several.

Comment: In short, what you are probably thinking is "this query in the title is shorter and thus better because it's concise... how can I generate it instead of the more verbose version?" but that inquiry is based on the incorrect assumption that it means the short version and the long version mean/select the same values (they do not).

Comment: And I see this all the time; beginners try to write `if` statements for multiple variables (or columns) as they would read/write it in their native language, like `if A and B are greater than 100`. Incorrect: `if (a && b > 100)` vs correct: `if (a > 100 && B > 100)`. The "incorrect" one actually equates to `if (a == true && b > 100)`, which is very different from the "correct" one.

Comment: `WHERE (column_1 OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)` means `WHERE (column_1 IS TRUE OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @TimLewis both are valid statements, as they both return results instead of errors when I run them :3

Comment: Yes I know, I can't edit that comment, but I didn't really mean "valid" in that sense. See the rest of the comments to see what I meant.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for a quick and correct explanation! I think I understand now; I need 
where('column_1', true) and orWhereNotNull(column_2)!

Comment: @TimLewis I see :)
As stated in my question, just below the code snippet I ask for an explanation of the queries, as they give different results. I understand now, thank you for helping!

Comment: @jarlh Yes, I incorrectly assumed the title statement returns results where one or both column_1 column_2 are not null.

Comment: Haha yes, and in giving the explanation, it raised another question "which query do you mean to use, as they equate quite differently". Glad you got it working now though, cheers 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andrew pointed out in the comment to op, I incorrectly assumed that query

```
WHERE (column_1 OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)
```

checks both columns for null value, and returns all results where eirther column_1, column_2 or both are not null.

The query in fact checks column_1 for true/false, and column_2 for null, and returns results where column_1 is true or column_2 is not null or both.

Eloquent code that outputs a query like that is:

```
$query = DB::table('your_table')
    ->where('column_1', true)
    ->orWhereNotNull('column_2')
```

Edit: As @Ali Raza pointed out, you must also use a `where closure` to make the query builder output the query exactly as it is in the question (with parantheses);

```
$query = DB::table('your_table')
    ->where(function (Builder $q) {
        $q->where('column_1 ', true)
          ->orWhereNotNull('datumPrenosa');
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `where closure` on Eloquent.

```
$results = 
YOUR_MODEL::where(function($query) {
     $query->whereNotNull('column_1')
         ->orWhereNotNull('column_2');
    })->get();
```

This will generate a query with a WHERE clause that looks like `(column_1 IS NOT NULL OR column_2 IS NOT NULL)`.